# Count doesn't print it correctly

Tags: c

I have following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, br, j=1, zbroj=0;

    printf("Ucitati cijeli broj(manji od 1000):\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(br=1; br<=n; br++)
    {
        if(br % 6 == 0)
            printf("%d ", br);
        j = br;
        while(j != 0)
        {
            if(j % 6 == 0)
                zbroj++;
            j /= 6;
        }
    }

    printf("\nPerica je zapisao %d cifara\n", zbroj);

    return 0;
}
```

As I was doing some practice in C, I encountered on unusual problem.So my count(`zbroj`) prints how many numbers were printed(in this case 3). But it won't print how many digits it has(if I input 18, it should print total digits (6,12,18), and that is 5 digits)). So I'm little confused why it prints total of numbers, but not total of digits.

Comment: 1) it will help you greatly is you use meaningful variable names – do you really think 67 months from now you will know what `br` means? 2) Get an IDE with a debugger (Visual Studio, Eclipse, Code::blocks, etc), learn to set a breakpoint and then step through your code line by line, examining the variables, and you will soon see the problem. That way, you won't need to wait for help in future. The debugger is the most powerful tool a developer has, so best ;learn how to use it.

Comment: You don't need an IDE to debug C programs.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: What is "*count*"?

Comment: @Mawg I'm writhing this in CodeBlocks, and these variables are short words in my language, and yes I'm kinda getting used to write these words in English

Comment: @alk  I will read that, and count I use for incrementation

Comment: If `n==0`, what should print out? `"Perica je zapisao 1 cifara"`?

Comment: Well, I will believe that `zbroj ` is a word, but `br? and `j`? :-) Anyway, great news that you use code::blocks. Do you know how to use the debugger? If you do, you can easily solve this yourself. If you don, please stop coding & learn the debugger. You will be amazed at how helpful it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place the value if `zbroj` is modified is in the loop:

```
j = br;
while(j != 0)
{
    if(j % 6 == 0)
        zbroj++;
    j /= 6;
}
```

This is not going to count the number of digits in each number. It's going to count the number of times each number is divisible by 6 into `zbroj`.

To count digits, you can replace your loop with:

```
if (br % 6 == 0)
{
    printf("%d ", br);
    j = br;
    while (j != 0)
    {
        zbroj++;
        j /= 10;
    }
}
```

Also notice that I moved the `while` loop into the scope of the `if` statement so that only the numbers that are actually printed out are counted by `zbroj`.

For brevity, you could also `#include <math.h>` and use `(int) log10(j) + 1` to count digits on a match.

Comment: ahh that log10 part is cool dude, learned a new thing today
Thanks

Comment: @Govind Parmar Yeah, I kept making same mistake with count over and over again, I get your point and thanks for the tip

Comment: `log10(j)` fails when `j <= 0`.  `log10(j)` can fail with positive numbers near powers of 10 due to precision issues.  With select machine whose `int` precession exceeds `double`,  `log10(j)` introduces rounding error in the conversion to `double`.  I recommend against using `log10()` for this task.  The `while (j != 0)
    {
        zbroj++;
        j /= 10;
    }` results in `zbroj == 0` when `j==0`.  Often `0` is considered 1 digit.